# SCP and backing up data

Tags: linux, backup, network-attached-storage, scp

I have a user on my Linux NAS box running barebones and I want to setup SCP but without Shell access and I ONLY want it to access one folder. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible , You can set the shell of the user to : /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

```
root@host # usermod -s /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server username
```

Try to find the location of `sftp-server` because it may be placed in different location.

Answer (score -1):

https://superuser.com/a/149408

It looks like this has already been answered before. You might also consider installing rssh.

EDIT

I inadvertently linked to the question rather than the answer. The new link is to the answer describing how to get the results you're looking for.